# Running Assembler load got abend s0c1

Tags: assembly, zos

Hey guys i want to run my first assembly program on IBM

this is the JCL

```
//JRETEST JOB (A925,22360679777),'AESANJA',NOTIFY=&SYSUID,
//        MSGLEVEL=(1,1)                                  
//PROCLIB JCLLIB ORDER=IBMUSER.LEARN.ASMJCL               
//     EXEC ASMACLG                                        
//SYSOUT DD SYSOUT=*                                      
//C.SYSIN DD *                                            
TEST   START 0                                            
       PRINT NOGEN                                        
*      SAMPLE PROGRAM                                     
       BASR 15,0                                          
       USING *,15                                         
       WTO 'ADRIAN EKA SANJAYA'                           
       RETURN (14,12),RC=0                                
       END TEST                                           
/*                                                        
//L.SYSLMOD DD UNIT=SYSDA,SPACE=(CYL,(5,5)),              
//    DISP=SHR,DSN=IBMUSER.LEARN.ASMLOAD(LEARN001)
```

---

And got this error message , can anyone fix the code for me ? :D
I very appriciate your help because i dont fully understand yet about Assembly

```
20.27.08 JOB00678 ---- MONDAY,    30 OCT 2017 ----                            
20.27.08 JOB00678  IRR010I  USERID IBMUSER  IS ASSIGNED TO THIS JOB.          
20.27.08 JOB00678  IEF677I WARNING MESSAGE(S) FOR JOB JRETEST  ISSUED         
20.27.08 JOB00678  ICH70001I IBMUSER  LAST ACCESS AT 19:41:40 ON MONDAY, OCTOB
20.27.08 JOB00678  $HASP373 JRETEST  STARTED - INIT 1    - CLASS A - SYS SYS1 
20.27.08 JOB00678  IEF403I JRETEST - STARTED - TIME=20.27.08                  
20.27.09 JOB00678  +ADRIAN EKA SANJAYA                                        
20.27.09 JOB00678  IEA995I SYMPTOM DUMP OUTPUT  254                           
   254             SYSTEM COMPLETION CODE=0C1  REASON CODE=00000001           
   254              TIME=20.27.09  SEQ=00033  CPU=0000  ASID=001A             
   254              PSW AT TIME OF ERROR  078D0000   00000002  ILC 2  INTC 01 
   254                NO ACTIVE MODULE FOUND                                  
   254                NAME=UNKNOWN                                            
   254                DATA AT PSW  00000000 - 000A0000  000130E1  00000000    
   254                AR/GR 0: 9D84CD16/00000000   1: 00000000/00000000       
   254                      2: 00000000/00000000   3: 00000000/00000000       
   254                      4: 00000000/00000000   5: 00000000/00000000       
   254                      6: 00000000/00000000   7: 00000000/00000000       
   254                      8: 00000000/00000000   9: 00000000/00000000       
   254                      A: 00000000/00000000   B: 00000000/00000000       
   254                      C: 00000000/00000000   D: 00000000/00006008       
   254                      E: 00000000/00000000   F: 00000000/00000000       
   254              END OF SYMPTOM DUMP                                       
20.27.09 JOB00678  IEF450I JRETEST G - ABEND=S0C1 U0000 REASON=00000001  255  
   255                     TIME=20.27.09                                      
20.27.09 JOB00678  IEF404I JRETEST - ENDED - TIME=20.27.09                    
20.27.09 JOB00678  $HASP395 JRETEST  ENDED                                    
------ JES2 JOB STATISTICS ------                                             
  30 OCT 2017 JOB EXECUTION DATE                                              
           17 CARDS READ                                                      
          416 SYSOUT PRINT RECORDS                                            
            0 SYSOUT PUNCH RECORDS                                            
           18 SYSOUT SPOOL KBYTES                                             
         0.01 MINUTES EXECUTION TIME
```

This job got an abend s0c1 u00000 reason code= 0000000001
thank you very much :))

Comment: I suggest you read and understand the [documentation for the WTO macro](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.ieaa900/iea3a9_Description24.htm).

Comment: The print out succsess fully on spool "Adrian Eka Sanjaya" , but why still got an abend?

Comment: Your base register is 15. WTO munches R15.

Comment: By the way, this is a great opportunity to add a SYSUDUMP DD statement to your JCL so that you can start learning to find these answers in a dump. In this case, it's pretty trivial - everything you need is right in the mini dump on the console log...from there, you can see a PSW that shows you took a branch to location zero, and as zarchasmpgmr points out, you can see your base register has zeros.

Comment: ...one other thing...the PRINT NOGEN isn't helping you - it hides the assembler that the WTO macro generated. If you had it, you'd probably notice a branch in there somewhere, and when you figured out that WTO sets R15 to zero, you might have found this a little easier.

Comment: To add to the other answers here, the other obvious problem is that you forgot to save your registers at entry...you have a RETURN (14,12) but no SAVE (14,12). If you'll look at the macro expansion of RETURN (that you'll see if you remove PRINT NOGEN), you'll see the RETURN generates a LM  off of R13 to reload the original registers, and then it branches to the return address in R14. Since you never saved anything in the save area pointed to by R13, this means you're loading whatever happened to be there into your registers - and this is why you see all the 0's in the console register dump.

Comment: Can't resist one other little tidbit...if  you replace your RETURN (14,12) with an SVC 3 instruction, then your program will run fine as is. When you can explain why this is the case, you'll definitely be well on your way to understanding assembler and z/OS. :)